# How to write recursive function in pseudocode for this number $a_n=n!+2^n$

Tags: recurrence-relation, pseudocode

I need to write **recursive function** in pseudocode for n-th number term of $a_n=n!+2^n$. Whole code should be contained in one function with $n$ as function argument.

Comment: What do you mean by "n-th string term"?  $a_n$ looks like a number to me; what do you mean by "this string"?  We're not particularly looking for posts that consist of an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve it for you.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163524/proving-a-sequence-formula-using-induction?noredirect=1

Answer (score 3):

Try to find simple functions $x=x(n)$ and $y=y(n)$ such that $a_{n+1} = x\cdot a_n + y\cdot a_{n-1}$.

Thus $(n+1)! + 2^{n+1}  = 
x n! + x 2^n   + y\cdot (n-1)! + y\cdot 2^{n-1}$.

Then, hoping for good luck, separate the factorial and 2-power parts.

$(n+1)! = 
x\cdot n!   + y\cdot (n-1)! $
and
$2^{n+1}  = 
x\cdot 2^n   + y\cdot 2^{n-1}$.

After simple divisions we see this is equivalent to

$n{\cdot}(n+1) = 
x\cdot n   + y$
and
$4  = 
x\cdot 2   + y$.

If you plug  $y = 4 -2x$ into the first equation you get a solution expressing $x(n)$ as a fractional function of $n$. This will give you $y(n)$ and thus a simple recurrence of order two for $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that we can find a simple recurrence of the form

$$a_n=f(n,a_{n-1}).$$

Following Jan's method for a recurrence on the previous two terms, we write

$$a_n=u(n)\,a_{n-1}+v(n)\,a_{n-2}$$
or
$$n(n-1)(n-2)!+4\,2^{n-2}=u(n)((n-1)(n-2)!+2\,2^{n-2})+v(n)((n-2)!+2^{n-2}).$$

Then by simple identification of the coefficients of the factorial and power,
$$\begin{cases}n(n-1)=(n-1)u(n)+v(v),\\4=2u(n)+v(n)\end{cases}$$
which gives
$$\begin{cases}u(n)=\dfrac{n^2-n-4}{n-3},\\v(n)=4-2u(n).\end{cases}$$

Answer (score -2):

$$a_{n} = n! + 2^{n}\\a_{n+1} = (n+1)! + 2^{n+1}\\a_{n+1}-a_{n}=(n+1)!+2^{n+1}-n!-2^{n}= (n+1)\cdot n!-n! + 2\cdot2^{n}-2^{n}=n\cdot n!+2^n$$

$$a_{n+1} = n\cdot n! + 2^n + a_{n}$$

Implementing/writing a pseudocode should be fairly straightforward, although there are more terms which can be calculated recursively.

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question.

Comment: A recursive function would require a recursive definition atleast.

Comment: For the answer to make sense, the recurrence should only involve constant-time operations (no factorial, no power).

Comment: Your recursive definition is as hard to compute as the closed expression, so there is no point to it.